# Can ElasticSearch create/store just the indexes while leaving the source document where it is?

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming I already have a set of documents living in some document store can I have ElasticSearch create its indexes and store them in its various replicated nodes while leaving the documents themselves where they are?  In other words can I use ES just for search and not for storage?  (I understand this might not be ideal but assume there are good reasons I need to keep the documents themselves where they are).

If I take this approach does it remove any functionality from search, for example showing where in a document the search term was found?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html

Answer (score 1):

The link Konstantin referenced should show you how to disable _source.

There is another way to store fields (store=true). You are better off using _source and excluding any specific fields you don't want stored as part of _source, though.

Functionality removed:

- Viewing fields that are returned from search
- Highlighting
- Easily rebuilding an index from _source. Probably not an issue, since data is stored elsewhere

There are probably other features I am missing.

The only case I've come across where I really don't need _source is when building an analytics engine where I am only returning aggregates (term and histogram).